# TYPO3 Extension News (tx_news) show & link tags at detail page

Tags: tags, typo3, fluid, detailview, tx-news

I'm using `TYPO3 7.6.2`with the extension `news`(4.1.0) ...  I'm showing the news `tags` at my detail page (`own template : Resources/Private/Extensions/News/Templates/News/Detail.html`).

At list view it's no problem to show & hyperlink a list of `tags`.
But not at detail view.I can show them but how can I link the seperate tags as well?

```
<f:for each="{newsItem.tags}" as="tag">
  <f:link.page title="{tag.title}" pageUid="{tag.uid}" additionalParams="{tx_news_pi1:{overwriteDemand:{tags: tag}}}">
    {tag.title}
   </f:link.page>
 </f:for>
```

The `uid`is wrong, see screenshot. How can I make a link from detail- to tag-list-view with the corresponding `tag`?

[image: debug]

Answer (score 1):

It just works with a page ID, which contains a news list:

```
<f:link.page title="{tag.title}" pageUid="{22}" additionalParams="{tx_news_pi1:{overwriteDemand:{tags: tag}}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the uid as a page uid, thus gives you the wrong link.
You need to link to a page where you have a list of the news items with a certain tag :

```
 <f:link.page title="{tag.title}" pageUid="{settings.mynewssettings.pageidoftaglist}" additionalParams="{tx_news_pi1:{overwriteDemand:{tags: tag}}}">
```

Comment: It must be `pageUid="{settings.listPid}"`the normal News List .. but thats wrong